# How to integrate/use OrgChart plugin with React JS

Tags: reactjs, orgchart

I'm looking for a react plugin to display an organization chart based on the JSON data that I pass to it in my React application. I need basic functionality like if a user clicks on an employee in the org chart, then I get back whole profile info of that employee in return. I have searched for it and came up with "OrgChart" plugin but now I don't understand how I can use this plugin with react.js because I am a beginner in react.js so don't know how to integrate.so It would be helpful If you could provide me with the code.

I have seen [this](https://codepen.io/dabeng/pen/eyXJJq) link but again due to less knowledge failed to understand where to put the below code with proper file hierarchy in react.js.

```
class OrgChart extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.$el = $(this.el);
    let datascource = {
      'name': 'Lao Lao',
      'title': 'general manager',
      'children': [
        { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager',
          'children': [
            { 'name': 'Tie Hua', 'title': 'senior engineer' },
            { 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer',
              'children': [
                { 'name': 'Pang Pang', 'title': 'engineer' },
                { 'name': 'Xiang Xiang', 'title': 'UE engineer' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        { 'name': 'Hong Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'name': 'Chun Miao', 'title': 'department manager' }
      ]
    };

    this.$el.orgchart({
      'data' : datascource,
      'nodeContent': 'title',
      'pan': true,
      'zoom': true
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.$el.empty();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="chart-container" ref={el => this.el = el}></div>
    );
  }
}

function Example() {
  return (
    <div>
      <OrgChart></OrgChart>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried this Codepen example.

First of all, you need to install **jquery** and **orgchart** (I'm using npm for that).
For TypeScript also install **@types/jquery**.

Then you need to import them into your React component.

```
import $ from "jquery";
const orgchart = require("orgchart");
```

(To allow this import I have also added ***"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true*** to the tsconfig.json's compilerOptions.)

You will also need to declare your **$el** and **el** fields in the component:

```
public $el;
public el;
```

Now it's ready, you can add the given componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount to your component and return

```
<div id="chart-container" ref={el => this.el = el}></div>
```

from your render method.

Comment: Because I don't use typescript, I don't need those two public declarations. The code runs as expected. Btw, the Codepen example leads me to find solution not only for this orgchart plugin, but also other jquery plugin. Immediately I remember the section in the React doc that discusses integration with other libraries, esp jquery.